# What podcast app supports podcasts that require basic authentication?

Tags: podcast

I subscribe to podcasts that require paid subscriptions.  It works fine on iTunes, but I can't find a (free) Android app that supports Podcasts that require basic authentication.  Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BeyondPod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beyondpod-podcast-manager/mobi.beyondpod) supports Feed Authentication.  I use the pro version which costs $7, but if you choose not to go pro there are [only a few limitations](http://groups.google.com/group/beyondpod/browse_thread/thread/ad529454d6ef9c28/2839fbd636e71e73?lnk=gst&q=lite#2839fbd636e71e73).  The free lite version should still handle Authentication.